# jsconfig.json path alias not working properly

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I have a react project created using create-react-app, and I'm trying to add material kit react to the project. I have placed the assets and components of material kit react under src/template and I would like to change the path of assets from src/assets to src/template/assets.
The problem is when I configured `jsconfig.json` to define the path for assets alias I get the error "Module not found" when using assets, but if I use the template alias it works just fine.
Here is my `jsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "target": "es6",
    "paths": {
      "template/*": ["src/template/*"],
      "assets/*": ["src/template/assets/*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

If someone can help me to understand why the template alias is working and not the assets alias.

Answer (score 1):

please try the code below.
I think your 'baseUrl' is wrong.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "target": "es6",
    "paths": {
      "template/*": ["./src/template/*"],
      "assets/*": ["./src/template/assets/*"]
  }
},
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

So, This will make VS Code IntelliSense work.

But there may be other issues. (..Because I went through it.)
Other issue is that resolve does not work.
error is the same

```
This dependency was not found:
* template/somtething in ./blahblah..
To install it, you can run: npm install --save template/somtething`
```

If there is an error above,
try to set an alias to the 'template' folder using the following Webpack configuration.

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/